# DAX - How to sum the most recent values by group?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables, the first is a sanitised version of the data, the second is what I need to calculate.

```
AnimalCount
Animal  DATE        Count
Lion    2019-01-01  2
Cat     2019-01-01  45
Cat     2019-01-02  40
Fish    2019-01-02  900
Cat     2019-01-03  50
Fish    2019-01-05  800
Fish    2019-01-06  1200
Cat     2019-01-07  45
Lion    2019-01-07  1
Lion    2019-01-08  0



Calculated
DATE (unique)   Sum of latest Count by Animal
2019-01-01      47 = 45 Cats + 2 Lions
2019-01-02      942 = 900 Fish + 40 Cats + 2 Lions
2019-01-03      952 = 50 Cats + 900 Fish + 2 Lions
2019-01-05      852 = 800 Fish + 50 Cats + 2 Lions
2019-01-06      1252 = 1200 Fish + 50 Cats + 2 Lions
2019-01-07      1246 = 1 Lion + 45 Cats + 1200 Fish
2019-01-08      1245 = 45 Cats + 1200 Fish
```

Here are the queries I've tried so far, both of them give slightly different results to what I'm looking for.

I'd be super grateful for any suggestions?

```
Query 1.
LatestTotal = SUMX(
    GROUPBY(
        FILTER(
            AnimalCount,
            [DATE] <= EARLIER([DATE])
        ),
        [Animal],
        "LatestGroupTotal",
        SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), [Count])
    ),
    [LatestGroupTotal]
)

Query 2.
LatestTotal = SUMX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            VALUES(AnimalCount[Animal]),
            "AnimalName",
            [Animal],
            "LastDate",
            CALCULATE(
                MAX(AnimalCount[DATE]),
                NOT(ISBLANK(AnimalCount[Count]))
            )
        ),
        "LastValue",
        SUMX(
            FILTER(
                AnimalCount,
                [AnimalName] = [Animal]
                && [DATE] = [LastDate]
            ),
            [Count]
        )
    ),
    [LastValue]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, create a measure for total animal count (for further convenience):

```
Total Animal Count = SUM(AnimalCount[Count])
```

Then, add this measure:

```
Latest Total = 
VAR 
   Current_Date = MAX ( AnimalCount[DATE] )
VAR 
   All_Latest_Dates =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( 
        ALL ( AnimalCount[Animal] ),
        "Last Date", CALCULATE ( 
                         MAX ( AnimalCount[DATE] ), 
                         AnimalCount[DATE] <= Current_Date )
    )
VAR Animal_Latest_Dates =
    TREATAS ( All_Latest_Dates, AnimalCount[Animal], AnimalCount[DATE] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( [Total Animal Count], Animal_Latest_Dates )
```

Result:

[image]

Explanation:

This formula requires an understanding of "data lineage" concept in DAX:

[Understanding Data Lineage in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-data-lineage-in-dax/)

In short:

- store date visible in a current context in a variable;
- then, generate a virtual table ("All_Latest_Dates"), that consists of all animals, and their last known date for each "current" date;
- next, apply this virtual table to the AnimalCount table using TREATAS (please read the article to understand how it works);
- finally, calculate animal count using the virtual table as a new filter context.

This approach results in an optimal query execution plan, and the formula should give you good performance even if your data is large.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! At home now but will have a look when am back at work

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
LatestTotal =
VAR CurrDate =
    MAX ( AnimalCount[DATE] )
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( AnimalCount ), AnimalCount[DATE] <= CurrDate ),
        AnimalCount[Animal],
        "LastDate", MAX ( AnimalCount[DATE] )
    )
VAR CountAtDate =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        Summary,
        "Count", LOOKUPVALUE (
            AnimalCount[Count],
            AnimalCount[Animal], [Animal],
            AnimalCount[DATE], [LastDate]
        )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( CountAtDate, [Count] )
```

First, we summarize the table by `Animal` looking for the last date associated with each one that is less than or equal to the date of the row we're in (`CurrDate`).

Then we look up the count for that animal on that date and add all those counts together.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! At home now but will have a look when am back at work